# Asterisk Server Pass Variable from Dialplan to AGI Script

Tags: php, asterisk, asteriskami, agi

My Dialplan is like this

```
[dial-plan]
exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,n,Noop(exten = ${EXTEN}
exten => s,n,Macro(dumpvars)
exten => s,n,Macro(record-enable)
exten => s,n,AGI(success.php)
exten => i,1,Noop(REASON = ${REASON})
exten => i,n,Macro(dumpvars)
exten => i,n,AGI(faile.php)
exten => failed,1,Noop(REASON = ${REASON})
exten => failed,n,Macro(dumpvars)
exten => failed,n,AGI(faile.php)
```

I want to catch from where faile.php called , It may be called from `failed` or from `i` . How can I check this

I need to make like this is faile.php

```
if($some_var == 1){
     //Invalid
}
elsif($some_var == 2){
    //Failed
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I implemented same with [php-agi.php](http://phpagi.sourceforge.net/)

### failed.php  (will execute  if call  failed)

```
<?php
    require_once "phpagi.php";
    require_once "phpagi-asmanager.php";

    $astman = new AGI();
    $astman->set_variable('CallState','failed');

?>
```

### success.php (will execute  if call  success)

```
<?php
    require_once "phpagi.php";
    require_once "phpagi-asmanager.php";

    $astman = new AGI();
    $astman->set_variable('CallState','success');

?>
```

### hangup.php  (will execute on end of the call, if call failed or success)

```
<?php
    require_once "phpagi.php";
    require_once "phpagi-asmanager.php";

    $astman = new AGI();
    $call_state = agi_get_var('CallState');
    if($call_state == "success"){
        //call was success
    }
    elseif($call_state == "failed"){
        //call was failed
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The agi will be called with some standard paramaters, include the called-from extension (in your case, that will be `i` or `failed`). Make sure you are parsing the arguments being passed to your script (via stdin)!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to pass a variable to your PHP AGI script.
Here's how to do it:

```
exten => i,n,AGI(faile.php,invalid)

exten => failed,n,AGI(faile.php,failed)
```

And then, your PHP AGI script should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
set_time_limit(30);
//load PHP AGI
require('phpagi/phpagi.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$agi = new AGI();

$status = $argv[1];

if($status == "invalid")
{
  // invalid
} else
{ 
  // failed
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [phpagi.php](http://phpagi.sourceforge.net/) in your script, it provide all required parsing for AGI.

Or see examples at http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI+php

Answer (score 0):

In Dialplan

```
exten => _*999*.,1,Answer()
exten => _*999*.,n,Set(var1=1) 
exten => _*999*.,n,AGI(test.php,${var1})
```

In php

```
<?php
    require('phpagi.php');

    $agi = new AGI();

    $agi->say_digit($argv[1]);

    $agi->hangup();
?>
```